# Meta tag in JavaScript and Html scripts assuring web browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, meta

I would like to get some advice regarding including meta tag assuring compatibility with IE 8. The thing is that my html code contained meta tag:

```
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"
```

However it did not work because before the line with meta tag some javascripts had been running by the application in response render method:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new CssResourceReference(BasePage.class, "CSSPage.css")));
}
So that the line with meta tag conforming the web browser compatibility had been placed further,  not at the first place, so in consequence ignored.
```

I was trying to put some javaScripts lines  in the code which were supposed to put meta tag at the beginnig of the html script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var meta = '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />';
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', meta);
});
```

It did not work either.

I would be grateful for any advice how to improve the code to make it compatible with desired web browser version: IE 8.

Cheers and Thanks,
JaneElle
It did not work either.

I would be grateful for any advice how to improve the code to make it compatible with desired web browser version: IE 8.

Cheers and Thanks,
JaneElle

Comment: A meta tag inserted after the page has been parsed (or after 4k of code has been parsed) has no influence on the page. Also, the `X-UA-Compatible` should be placed in the document before any other code defines the document mode.

Answer (score 2):

Having `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` in your page doesnt make it compatabile with that browser, I think you are confused on the usage.

> The idea behind compatibility mode is to allow web sites and applications that are not designed to modern standards to continue to work while upgrades can be made, allowing end users to upgrade to the latest browser version.

read up on [x-ua compatability](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible) here.

Comment: Exactly. You add this meta tag if you have an old website that shows wrong in a newer version of IE so to force IE 10 to use the engine of IE 8 for that page. However, if you want to use this tag for the right pourpose, dont' add it dinamically so it will not works.